# New print job not working out well

Tags: print-quality, print-failure

I'm just learning and have calibrated my new Bambu Lab P1P 3D Printer. I printed the built-in scraper—amazing quality.

But I downloaded this [Stiga Ping Pong Table Feet](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5424843)

And printed this twice to get this result:

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with errors]

My next print job did the same:

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model after the first few layers where the model did not stick to the build plate]

It seemed like the part wasn't staying on the bottom and that was messing everything up.

Ideas? lessons learned?

Comment: one thing I did was slow down the speed by 50% on the second job

Comment: Welcome to 3D printing - this kind of problem solving and the resulting success is a big part of why we do it.

Comment: Slowing down is actually very well for getting it better to stick, but bed temperature and correct setup (enough squish on the first layer) are at least as important as well.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably this is caused by an adhesion problem. When the first layer doesn't stick well enough, this could be related to wrong bed temperature, incorrect distance between nozzle and bed, incorrect initial layer height and incorrect print temperature.

When the print detaches from the bed it will wander over the place creating blobs and spaghetti-like objects as shown in your images.

Comment: I think I had the "cold plate" setting that was causing the problem.

Comment: That falls under "related to wrong bed temperature" ;)